# how to use the fviz_cluster cluster visualization package when the first column of my data has a column name

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I am using the fviz_cluster package.   There is a nice tutorial at https://afit-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering where it shows how to use the package to visualize the clusters.   That is all straightforward.  The data they use for the tutorial is df <- USArrests.   When viewing the data it shows as

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Murder  : num  13.2 10 8.1 8.8 9 7.9 3.3 5.9 15.4 17.4 ...
 $ Assault : int  236 263 294 190 276 204 110 238 335 211 ...
 $ UrbanPop: int  58 48 80 50 91 78 77 72 80 60 ...
 $ Rape    : num  21.2 44.5 31 19.5 40.6 38.7 11.1 15.8 31.9 25.8 ...
```

The dataframe first column that has the key of each observation does not have a column header.   With that, the package works great.

my data has a column header obviously.   How should I make my data appear like the USArrests so this works, but then I need to append the cluster number back to the data?

My data has 11 columns including the first column with the observation name so I did the clustering by skipping the first column using

```
[,2:11]

when I use this to visualize using 
fviz_cluster(allLfit, data = allLdf[,2:11])
```

it works but the plot uses ambiguous names

Any suggestions??

Thanks!!!

```
structure(list(PIN = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e"), class = "factor"), v1 = c(0.8, 0.36, 0.21, 0.84, 0.43
), v2 = c(0.87, 0.01, 0.56, 0.75, 0.98), v3 = c(0.48, 0.13, 0.26, 
0.34, 0.83)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of head your dataset for testing.  Your statement `my data has a column header obviously.` is not clear.  `USArrests` dataset also have column name

Comment: Hello and Thank you for the response.   I added a data set.   the first column in this example data set is "PIN".   in the fvis example tutorial, that column name is not included in the columns, but shows up in the output of the fvis visualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the same procedure in the [link](https://afit-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering), `scale`d the numeric columns to create 'df', while setting the `row.names` as the first column, get the `kmeans` ('k2') and use `fviz_cluster` on the 'k2' specifying the 'df' as the `scale`d dataset

```
library(factoextra)
library(cluster)
df <- scale(`row.names<-`(allLdf[-1], allLdf[[1]]))
k2 <- kmeans(df, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
fviz_cluster(k2, data = df)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.   However what I am after is the label of each row in the plot like the example shows (I copied a screen shot above in the question

Comment: the data is scaled in a previous step.   What would the df <- scale(`row.names<-`(allLdf[-1], allLdf[[1]])) be less the scale step, just converting "df"?

Comment: @DataScienceDave you need to convert the data before the scaling i.e. `allLdfnew <- allLdf[-1]; row.names(allLdfnew) <- allLdf[[1]]`,  then you can directly use `df <- scale(allLdfnew)`

Comment: @akkrun - Wow look at that!   Perfect!   Thank you!   This is new code for me.   Any suggestions on where I could learn more about this, or where should I have learned this???   Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DataScienceDave I think the issue was that you were only looking at `str(USArrests)` which didn't show the dim attributes,   You may also have to check `dimnames(USArrests)` which will gives the rownames and column names as a `list` or just `row.names(USArrests)`

Comment: @DataScienceDave There are many avenues to learn nowadays  i.e through paid courses, youtube videos, blogs etc.  But, programming needs. practise as well i.e. you may need to spend at least half an hour daily on the programming language